# how to resolve the error 'expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm not able to test the click on 2 subcomponents of my react component, does anyone know how to help?

```
<Container>
    <Checkbox
       data-testid='Checkbox'
       checked={checked}
       disabled={disabled}
       onClick={handleCheckboxChange}
    />
            
  
    <Item
      data-testid='Label'
      disabled={disabled}
      onClick={handleCheckboxChange}
     >
       {label}
    </Item>
    </Container>
```

my test

```
    it('textLabel enabled', () => {
        const onClick = jest.fn();
        render(<Checkbox label='item 1' onClick={onClick} />);
        userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(Label'));
        expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I can't test the click on the Item, it gives an error in the test

expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing

```
render(<Checkbox label='item 1' onClick={onClick} />);
```

The label here is 'item 1', and not 'Label'
What you are doing is, simulating click event on 'Label' instead of doing it on 'Item 1'

so you need to do

```
userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('item 1'));
```